# Text showing up I need to hide

Tags: jquery

I've got a site I'm working on and there's a file path that's being output in the HTML that needs fixing (I don't have access to the DB to fix it).  I've got a div with a class of "header_vs2".  The text shows up (assets/templates/tides/images/no-logo.gif) that is referencing an image but there's no open and close image tags:

```
<div class="header_vs2">

<div class="header_vs2_social_media blank">
&nbsp;
</div><!-- end .header_vs2_social_media -->

assets/templates/tides/images/no-logo.gif

</div>
```

How do I write a jQuery statement that when this image path shows up that I insert before the statement an open image tag and close tag after the file path?  My goal is to get this:

```
<div class="header_vs2">

<div class="header_vs2_social_media blank">
&nbsp;
</div><!-- end .header_vs2_social_media -->

<img src="assets/templates/tides/images/no-logo.gif" />

</div>
```

Comment: explain little bit clear

Comment: whether u need to insert an image. When u want to insert

Comment: Stefan H down below was able to provide this fix: http://jsfiddle.net/6PNHj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on for size

```
$('.header_vs2').html($('.header_vs2').html().replace('assets/templates/tides/images/no-logo.gif', '<img src="assets/templates/tides/images/no-logo.gif" />'));
```

You can see it in action at this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/6PNHj/

Comment: Awesome...that did the trick...thanks!  The only thing missing was the semicolon at the end.  Otherwise, worked like a charm.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
var $header = $(".header_vs2");
var path =  $header.text();
$header.text("").append("<img src=\"" + path + "\" />");
```

Comment: I couldn't quite get this one to work.  Maybe I wasn't implementing it correctly.  Any luck at getting it to run on jsfiddle?